# "Keyboard Layout Handler" is not working properly on Lubuntu 18.04

Tags: lubuntu, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, 18.04

Here is what I did:
[image]

- I disabled "Keep system layouts" in settings.
- Added my secondary language (Arabic) to keyboard layouts.
- Modified the layout change keys to: "Alt+Shift" and "Left Alt+Left Shift".

My (right) "Alt+Shift" keys successfully change the language from English to Arabic but never back! Left Alt+Left Shift are working just fine.

Being right-handed I really need to get the right Alt+Shift keys to successfully swap between the two input languages.

OS: Lubuntu 18.04 x64 - I clean-installed it today.

Comment: How did you even get the screen shot? I don't have this thing called the **keyboard layout hander.** Did you install it from somewhere?

Comment: @itsols It is a panel applet. You can add it to your panel. https://imgur.com/download/PQN9jI7

Answer (score 1):

When the Arabic layout is effective, <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> is defined (by default) as the key to access 3:rd and 4:th level symbols. That's probably the reason why you can't use it to switch back to English.

You have two options. Either

- start using some other shortcut for switching layouts, or
- explicitly define some other key but <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> to access 3:rd and 4:th level symbols.

Comment: But I used to use the same software with same shortcut without any problems!

Comment: @EbramShehata: It's hard for me to comment on that. I think you'll notice a difference if you add `lv3:ralt_alt` to the list of layout options. But then you won't be able to access 3:rd and 4:th level symbols on the Arabic layout. For that you need yet another option; which one depends on which key you want to use for the purpose.